# Include namespace in xmltodict.unparse output

Tags: python, xml-namespaces, xmltodict

I use `xmltodict` to convert Python dictionaries to XML. I would like to include the namespaces. What I've come up with is this:

```py
xml_dict = {
    "http://namespace.org:workflow":
        {"action-list": "..."}
}
namespaces = {"http://namespace.org": "ws"}
xml = xmltodict.unparse(xml_dict, namespaces=namespaces,
                        pretty=True, short_empty_elements=True, full_document=False)
```

That gives me the result:

```xml
<ws:workflow>
    <action-list>...</action-list>
</ws:workflow>
```

How can I include the namespaces in the result? I would like something like this:

```xml
<ws:workflow xmlns:ws="http://namespace.org">
```

Is there a simple solution using `xmltodict`?

**Note:** I've checked all keyword arguments in the source code of `unparse` and `_emit` functions. I guess the `preprocessor` argument will be the key to a better solution. But it's not documented.

Answer (score 0):

Not nice, and not a general solution to add *all the* namespaces, but works.

```py
import xmltodict


xml_dict = {
    "http://namespace.org:workflow":
        {
            "@REPLACE_THIS": "http://namespace.org",
            "action-list": "..."
        }
}
namespaces = {"http://namespace.org": "ws"}
xml = xmltodict.unparse(xml_dict, namespaces=namespaces, pretty=True, short_empty_elements=True, full_document=False)
xml = xml.replace("REPLACE_THIS", "xmlns:ws", 1)
print(xml)
```

That gives me exactly what I want:

```xml
<ws:workflow xmlns:ws="http://namespace.org">
    <action-list>...</action-list>
</ws:workflow>
```

The third argument in the replace function makes it sure that not other occurrences of `"REPLACE_THIS"` will be replaced, just the first one.